# c++ an object as parameter

Tags: c++, class, object, oop

My professor is asking us to code something that takes an object that contains values and take that object and make it a parameter for another object. Here is how it looks like
There are two classes. ScoreEntry and CourseEntry. ScoreEntry takes values (like s1 here) and courseentry (c1) evaluates the values such as add, remove, rank, etc.

```
 s1 = new ScoreEntry(“Jill”, 45, “02/05/2021”); // one entry
 c1.add(s1); // assume s1 (ScoreEntry): Jill 45 02/05/2021
```

what will be the add() function look like in this case? the scoreentry parameters are (spring, int, spring).

Comment: what exactly is the problem?
`CourseEntry::add(ScoreEntry entryToAdd)` or what exactly do you want?

Comment: _"Don't ask about...

Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ [tour]

Comment: How do I use objects as parameters for other objects

Comment: What do you mean with _"parameters for other objects"_? Objects don't have parameters. Functions have parameters. `c1.add(s1);` is the member function call with an object as argument and `CourseEntry::add(ScoreEntry entryToAdd)` is a possible declaration of this member function.

Comment: my bad. How can I use objects that contain values as parameters for my functions. In the case of my original question, the add() function.

Comment: There is no difference between objects in member functions and object somewhere else. Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: "My professor is asking us to code something that takes an object that contains values" You are not asking about that first part. If you show what you have for that, it will be easier to help you with the next step. Among other things it would probably solve the confusion I have about why it says "takes" where I expect "creates". It confuses me because with "takes" it sounds like it is expecting the second part to already be solved. Because "something takes an object" reads to me like "somethingelse created that object and made it a parameter for the something".

Comment: `std::string` is a class. You've been passing around instances of class types all along.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear but is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
class ScoreEntry{
        
        
        public:
            string n;
        int a;
        string d;
            ScoreEntry(string name, int age, string dob){
                a = age;
                n = name;
                d = dob;
                
            }
    
        
};

class CoursEntry{
    public:
    void add(ScoreEntry SE){
    
    }
};

int main(){
ScoreEntry ScoreEntry("Jill", 45, "02/05/2021");
CoursEntry c;
c.add(ScoreEntry);
}
```